# Embedded Service Chat Populate Supplied Name on Case

Tags: embedded-services

With an Embedded Chat Service, I want to populate the case's supplied name field with the name provided on the pre-chat form. Here is my extraPrechatInfo section. I can use "Last Name", but I'd like to concatenate First Name and Last Name. I can't figure out the syntax.

```
            embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatInfo = [{
              "entityFieldMaps": [{
                "doCreate":false,
                "doFind":true,
                "fieldName":"LastName",
                "isExactMatch":true,
                "label":"Last Name"
              }, {
                "doCreate":false,
                "doFind":true,
                "fieldName":"FirstName",
                "isExactMatch":true,
                "label":"First Name"
              }, {
                "doCreate":false,
                "doFind":true,
                "fieldName":"Email",
                "isExactMatch":true,
                "label":"Email"
              }],
              "entityName":"Contact"
            }, {
              "entityName": "Case",
              "showOnCreate": true,
              "saveToTranscript": "CaseId",
              "entityFieldMaps": [{
                "isExactMatch": false,
                "fieldName": "Subject",
                "doCreate": true,
                "doFind": false,
                "label": "Subject"
              }, {
                "isExactMatch": false,
                "fieldName": "Origin",
                "doCreate": true,
                "doFind": false,
                "label": "Origin"
              }, {
                "isExactMatch": false,
                "fieldName": "SuppliedEmail",
                "doCreate": true,
                "doFind": false,
                "label": "Email"
              }, {
                "isExactMatch": false,
                "fieldName": "SuppliedName",
                "doCreate": true,
                "doFind": false,
                "label": "Last Name"
              }]
            }];
```

Comment: did you managed to make this work? I face a similar issue.

Comment: Not with the javascript. I ended up making 2 custom fields on the case and then using a trigger to concatenate them.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this ended up being to create two new fields on the case called SuppliedFirstName__c and SuppliedLastName__c. I mapped to those two fields in the embedded chat code. Then using a before save trigger or a before save flow, concatenated those two fields and populated the SuppliedName field. It is important to note that the fields don't get populated on Insert, only on Update.